# Null value is considered an existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a validation into if conditional like:

```
IF(EXISTS
    (SELECT TOP 1 [TaskAssignationId]
     FROM [Task] AS [T]
          INNER JOIN @TaskIdTableType AS [TT] ON [T].[TaskId] = [TT].[Id]
))
```

But it returns `NULL`  value because `TaskAssignationId` is `NULL` so in consequence `IF` condition it's true because it exist with `NULL` value, but I don't want to consider NULL as a value. How can add an exception of nulls? Regards

Comment: `if (exists(select ... where TaskAssignationId is not null)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to include rows where [TaskAssignationId] is null then add that to a WHERE clause.

```
IF(EXISTS
    SELECT TOP 1 [TaskAssignationId]
    FROM [Task] AS [T]
    INNER JOIN @TaskIdTableType AS [TT] ON [T].[TaskId] = [TT].[Id]
    WHERE [TaskAssignationId] is not null  
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Exists works like "Did the (sub)query return more than zero (correlated) rows" not "did the (sub)query return a non null value"

These are perfectly valid exists:

```
SELECT * FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null FROM address a WHERE a.personid = p.id)

SELECT * FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM address a WHERE a.personid = p.id)

SELECT * FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM address a WHERE a.personid = p.id)
```

It doesn't matter what values you return, or how many columns, exists cares whether the rowcount is 0 or greater when determining whether results exist

Hence you have to make sure your (sub)query returns no rows if you want the exists check to fail. If Addresses that have a *null* type are unacceptable, the (sub)query has to exclude them with `WHERE a.type IS NOT NULL` so that only rows with a non null type are considered

There's also little point doing a TOP 1 in the (sub)query; the optimiser knows that the only condition it cares about is 0 or not-0 rows, so it automatically do a TOP 1 (i.e. it will stop retrieving data when it knows there is at least one row)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the existence then no need to assign the column name, you can use select 1

IF(EXISTS
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM [Task] AS [T]
    INNER JOIN @TaskIdTableType AS [TT] ON [T].[TaskId] = [TT].[Id] 
))
begin
----code---
end